# Reading webpage iframe content in c#

Tags: c#, html, iframe, web-scraping, webclient

I have been recently working in downloading webpage content using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) in C#. The `DownloadString` method of WebClient can not download the content from iframe.

The short code for downloading content has been used as:

```
   using (var client = new WebClient())
   {
        string html = client.DownloadString("url");
   }
```

What should I need to use for reading iframe content in C#?

For Testing, I am using http://multiprofits.co.uk/oddsmatcher.html site which has iframe in it.

Comment: Either use `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse the content manually and then load the `iframe` with another `DownloadString` request, or use `WebBrowser` (which supports [much more complex web scrapping scenarios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239357/how-to-cancel-task-await-after-a-timeout-period/22262976#22262976)).

Comment: The problem here is that iframe content getting from another DownloadString is not correct which has displayed in original webpage.

Comment: @akash88 duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429023/can-i-read-iframe-through-webclient-i-want-the-outer-html ?

Comment: @akash88, then use `WebBrowser`, follow the link I posted.

Comment: @PaulZahra : The issue is same with that solution as well.

Comment: @akash88 As Noseratio says... the solution in the link I gave uses the WebBrowser class, not WebClient... is that an issue?

Comment: @Noseratio : I have used WebBrowser control but not the way in the link you posted. The solution in the link differently handles the iframe content?

Comment: @akash88, with `WebBrowser`, it's as simple as this: `var frameDocument = webBrowser.Document.Window.Frames["iframeId"].Document`.

Comment: Yes, done that way as well but it returns Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: I guess the iframe content comes from a different domain, and you're facing cross-domain security restrictions (XSS). If that's the case, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18820169/1768303).

Comment: @akash88 Yes, indeed there is some security involved... try accessing the iframe directly... http://v2.oddsmatcher-data.co.uk/oddssearch.aspx?AffSiteID=325453&gridSkin=WebBlue gives "oddsmatcher is not permitted to run on this domain name" looks as though they've restricted the calling domain. I guess you could try spoofing your request as if it comes from their website... but that might be a little illegal depending on the rights of their data etc.

Comment: @akash88 Why not just try screen scraping it something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/599275/how-can-i-download-html-source-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Paul Zahra I have tried this solution but it doesn't work (cf. my post)

Comment: @christof13 I was thinking more along the lines of the post in the link I gave by Diego Jancic where he just creates a WebRequest and reads the stream.

Comment: @Paul Zahra I have tested the WebRequest solution but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

You have to search for the iframe tag in the main page and then take the src attribute to download the page in the iframe

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string html = client.DownloadString("url");
    string src = ... //find iframe source with regex
    string iframe = client.DownloadString(src);
}
```

For the regex you could use this [Regular Expression to get the SRC of images in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4257359/regular-expression-to-get-the-src-of-images-in-c-sharp)

Edit :

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            string html = client.DownloadString("http://multiprofits.co.uk/oddsmatcher.html");
            string src = Regex.Match(html, "<iframe.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
            Console.Write(client.DownloadString(src));
        }
```

You really get the iframe source with this code

Edit2 :

I have found your problem. It's a security issue from the site. Launch the iframe url in a new browser you will receive this message :

*oddsmatcher is not permitted to run on this domain name 
[v2.oddsmatcher-data.co.uk/v2.oddsmatcher-data.co.uk]
For more details please cotact support@oddsmonkey.com*

So you must can't download directly the iframe source. You probably have to use WebBrowser or something like this

Comment: I have doing that way too. But iframe content is not what it is display in web page.

Comment: I don't understand. The iframe src is the url of the page displayed. So if you download this page you will have the iframe content.

Comment: If the iframe page contains css, javascript,... you will have to download them too to display the page correctly. So you better to use a tool

Comment: You won't get actual iframe content from that iframe source url. I have already tried that :(

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I have already got iframe source URL. That's not the problem. The main issue is that I am not able to get correct iframe content with that source URL.

Comment: My code gives you the html source of the iframe no the url ! I don't understand why you say the content is incorrect. What do you do with that content ?

Comment: If you check the url I have posted, you can see content inside iframe i.e. grid which has data in it. But when you download content from iframe source url in code, you won't get those data. I want to get those data as well

Comment: Thank you for your update. So, is it not possible to get iframe data?