# Accessing content inside #document of a website

Tags: c#, html, wpf, dom

I would like to access content of a web-page using C#. The content is inside an i-Frame of the Body of the website, underlying an `#document` object. I am using this to read the page:

```
WebClient wbClient = new WebClient();
wbClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
byte[] raw = wbClient.DownloadData(stWebPage);
stWebPageContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
```

However, the relevant information inside the `#document` is ignored.

Can anybody explain what I have to do to access the needed info? It is nested under `body/div/iframe/#document/html/body/div/.....` Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** I am assuming `stWebPage` is pointing to a http url.

iFrame content will not be downloaded directly in this one call. You need to look for iFrame in `stWebPageContent` using `Regex` and pull the value in 'src' attribute, make another call to the src url for downloading content. More details can be found at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24325798/7292772).

Comment: Thanks alot. I think that helped :)